# How do I write a http triggered Firebase cloud function which registers users with input info from client

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am working on system admin part of my project which means that an already authenticated user should be able to register new accounts.

I have learned that this is possible with using Firebase cloud functions. I guess I need to send input values with `POST` trigger to function, then function will use this data to register user.

I read the documentation but couldn't find enough info about http `POST` request.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple. You can retrieve request body as below.

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const foo = req.body.foo;
    if (!foo) return res.status(400).send({
        message: 'foo is a required parameter.'
    });
    res.send({
        message: 'success'
    });
});
```

[This document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) would be helpful for you.

Comment: @dongerpep After deploy some `HTTP` code as above, and go to your firebase console's `functions` menu, it shows all the functions you deployed and you can find the `HTTP` function with some url address. The url is an endpoint of the function. Now you can just send request with `POST` from your android app and you can use any http client library. If you want to just check if the function is working, you can also use postman.